# Jquery -- Action fires on any event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there something in jquery where a function is triggered when any event is fired?

I'd like something like this:

```
$("*").anyEvent(function(){
  $("#error").html("");
});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$('*').on('blur change click dblclick error focus focusin focusout hover keydown keypress keyup load mousedown mouseenter mouseleave mousemove mouseout mouseover mouseup resize scroll select submit', function(){
  $('#error').empty();
});
```

...but would you want to do this?

Comment: Thanks. It's a little hard to explain why, and it's probably a slightly stupid thing to do anyway.

Comment: @Peter: yes, since this will **constantly fire** when the user does **anything**. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: +1 That has got to be the scariest statement i've ever seen.

Comment: @MattBall it could be used to remove validation error in combination with `.one(any event)`

Comment: This does not get custom events like bootstrap's `show.bs.dropdown`.  in addition `live` is [now deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/live/) in favor of `on`

Comment: @cwd this answer is 3 years old; you're welcome to suggest an edit.

Comment: Well, for curiosity sake? No one would activate this in production, nonetheless could be useful

Comment: I need this in production but with `one`. I need this to hide the cookie information banner after user does anything.

Comment: I also needed onwheel event as because rotating wheel upward didn't fire scroll event. And `contextmenu` too.