# How can I make an element trigger a function on any, and all events?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I don't think an explanation of my specific scenario would help much here.   So in short I need to know how I can call a function on any and all events.  The idea is to call the same function no matter what event happens to a specific element.

In my head the ideal way to do this would go something like:

```
<div onAnyEvent="function()"></div>
```

Rather than:

```
<div onClick="function()" onMouseover="function()" onKeypress="function()"></div>
```

Comment: you want to do it in pur JS or jquery will also do ???

Comment: I would like to do it in pure JS. Thanks for asking.

Comment: similar question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123356/jquery-action-fires-on-any-event



hope this help....

Comment: thats exactly what I want to do, except without the jquery part. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method I have found through research is to create an event listener for each event on the same element like so:

```
window.onload = addListeners;

function addListeners(){
  if(window.addEventListener){
    document.getElementById('message').addEventListener('keydown',textarea_resize,false);
    document.getElementById('message').addEventListener('keyup',textarea_resize,false);
    document.getElementById('message').addEventListener('keypress',textarea_resize,false);
}
```

To explain a little further:

`addEventListener('event to listen to', function_to_be_called, useCapture-value)`

The first parameter is the event you want to listen to (ie. `'click'` or `'keydown'`).

The second is the function that you want to call: (ie. `validate_form`).

-you can also send parameters into the function: `validate_form(e, i)`.

The last value for use capture will usually be set to `false` for most uses, and `false` is the automatic value if you don't specify any value.  Further explanation can be obtained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)!

So a full example might be: `document.getElementById('message').addEventListener('keydown',textarea_resize,false);` as I showed above.