# $(window).load(function() not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, perfect-scrollbar

I'm trying to implement a [scrollbar plugin](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) on a div on my website but I'm facing a few issues with it. first of all it was supposed to be working like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $('.chat-messages').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true});
  });
```

But I could only make it work like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    "use strict";
    $('.chat-messages').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true});
});
```

But with **window.load** the script doesn't seems to be working all the time, or at least the scroll bar doesn't always appear.

I'm not very familiar with js or jquery but I inserted the src file `perfect-scrollbar.js` in a folder and I'm calling it normally like this: `<script src="http://domain.com/javascript/perfect-scrollbar.js"></script>` on the header and puting the code that I described above with the **window.load** right after it between `<script></script>`. I'm assuming that this is a conflict with another document ready so I searched online for solutions and other ways to load it and I found the no conflict thingy and tried to implement like this:

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
     "use strict";
   $('.chat-messages').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true});
   });
});
```

but still no results, the only thing that this does is to stop all jquery of the website from working. Can anyone help me with this? thanks in advance

Comment: `noConflict` is to deal with conflicts between multiple versions of jQuery, not calls to it.

Comment: What does the HTML for the element you are targeting look like? Is it actually HTML or are you adding it with JS?

Comment: yes it is HTML like: <div class="chat-messages"> some content here </div>

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say? Are there any errors? What if you add `alert($('.chat-messages').length);`? Does it find the element?

Comment: yeah, like I said with the window.load it works fine, but I think it is supposed to be with the document ready for this reason. because window load not always get it to work right

Comment: I've done a test with document ready to display an alert and the alert appears, but the scroll bar still nothing so I think it must be on the code inside of it...

Comment: The alert should appear. What was the value displayed?

Comment: The alert appears but the scrollbar don't

Comment: **What value is displayed** (in the alert)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help guys, I've found this workaround solution here: [[src]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487472/jquery-when-element-becomes-visible)

```
var visible = true;
setInterval(
function()
{
    if(visible)
        if($('#element').not(':hidden'))
        {
            visible = false;
            "use strict";
            $('.chat-messages').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true});
        }
    else
        if($('#element').is(':hidden'))
        {
            visible = true;
            // do something
        }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tested, and `document.ready` should work fine.

**CSS**

```
.chat-messages {
    position: fixed;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**EDIT :**

Since you are combing this with other scripts, possibly try declaring your selector as a variable at the very top.

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var $chat = $('.chat-messages');

    ...other scripts/functions... 

    $chat.perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true});
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/455209yg/1/).

Comment: :\ maybe it's a problem somewhere in my script. maybe some lost JS on the script which is in conflict with it. Oh well.. I've tried so many things that I think I'm gonna give up of trying to make it work :\

Comment: can this be a problem of naming the function? how can I name it to try it out?

Comment: Are you combining this with another script or do you have it by itself? If you are combining it you probably have a traveral issue and `.chat-messages` can't be found in the DOM.

Comment: Yes I have it with another scripts, it's not by itself, that's why I thought the noConflict would solve the problem but no. I had tried to remove all the other script calls and left only the perfect scroll and still nothing.. :\

Comment: still nothing :/ I've done a test with document ready to display an alert and the alert seems to appear, but the scroll bar still nothing, so I think it must be on the code inside of it... I also tried some workaround ways and with this one it works well but the user will always have to scroll a bit for the scrollbar appear: `$(document).scroll(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $('.chat-messages').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX:    true});
});
```

is that you are leaving `$` undefined in your local scope by naming a parameter of your anonymous function with that identifier. jQuery passes no arguments to that function, but your declaration of the parameter masks the global definition of `$`. If you are not using no conflict mode, then `$` will already be available in the global scope, so the following should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $('.chat-messages').perfectScrollbar({suppressScrollX: true});
});
```

As an aside, the point of noConflict is to avoid clashes with other code which may be relying on a global definition of `$` which differs from jQuery's use of `$` as an alias for `jQuery`.

Comment: it´s still not working tho.. :\ How do I name the function with a random name? maybe that would fix the problem