# Wait for DOM element to be present/visible

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

I have a very simple requirement to load a web page, wait until it's finished loading, and then wait for an element to become present/visible (this only happens *after* the page has signaled that it finished loading) before doing anything else with the page.

I tried using the WebBrowser control, but struggled with finding a way to wait for the element.

I looked at using CefSharp but I was told the only way is to inject js, which I'm not all that keen on doing.

I also looked at Selenium WebDriver too and the `WebDriverWait` appears to do exactly what I want, but the fact that it's not actually a control, cannot be hidden and requires browsers to be installed is a no-no for me.

Is there a way of doing this which does not involve using `Thread.Sleep` in either WebBrowser, CefSharp or any other project I haven't mentioned yet?

**EDIT**: Some extra information...

I am using this for web automation. In this particular instance to login to a website (I'm not storing passwords, don't worry).

The particular website in question supports different authentication methods at a user level, so after entering the username it runs a js script which determines whether to then ask for the password or for something like phone auth, smartcard auth, etc. The js script does not fire the `DocumentCompleted` event, which is what I'm struggling with at the moment.

The idea is that if it asks for smartcard or phone auth to keep the form/control with `.Visible = false` the whole time and just show it if the user is set for username/password auth.

So depending on what happens after I automate entering the username, it will either ask for a password, smartcard or phone auth and I need to wait for the DOM to change so that one of those 3 elements becomes visible so I know what to do.

I dislike Selenium because it involves the user having to install browsers, it's hard/impossible to make it hidden, it's not an actual control I can drop on my form, etc etc.

Comment: WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted() is fired when the document is finished loading.

Comment: @Mathemats the DOM element only appears after that event is fired, I tried that already.

Comment: This is surely just JavaScript, but I'm confused by some of the language. When you say "I have a very simple requirement" - is this meant to be manual, occasional job, or a test scenario, or just a standard web dev thing where one element triggers another to do something? In which JQuery (or just standard JS) will cover all of it. E.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load. Even if your elem loads dynamically, you can just add a listener to that?

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. are you trying to load a web page within an Iframe?

Comment: Could you answer these question to confirm my understanding? 1. Do you use CefSharp to embed chromium into your application? 2. Are trying to open a web page on your application then check if the given element exists? 3. Does Selenium get the correct window (check webdriver.Title)?

Comment: You can use `WebDriver/Selenium` with `CefSharp`, see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md for a guide on how to use it with `CEF` (`CefSharp` is just a wrapper really)

Comment: Otherwise as you've already been suggested javascript is the key (At least in the context of `CefSharp`).

Comment: @Buaban 1. I am actually trying to do everything using the WebBrowser control, but have no problems with using CefSharp if that becomes easier. 2. Yes, with one small correction: **wait** until it exists (which happens after `DocumentCompleted` is fired). 3. I haven't tried Selenium on this project, I created a new one just to see what it was capable of and while I love the `WebDriverWait` the rest of Selenium doesn't quite fit my project. See my updated question for a better understanding.

Comment: JS is really the way, whether you have to listen for events, wait a while, poll etc. and no additional components to install. Does this sound a good fit? http://stackoverflow.com/q/20487472/954442, or else https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver (needs recent browsers)

Comment: @JohnUbuntu, see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20934538/1768303) helps.

Comment: @amaitland can you provide some example of how to do this using js in CefSharp?

Comment: here's an example: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/ScriptedMethods.cs#L105
This is the C# bound object with the RaiseEvent method that the JS invokes. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Example/ScriptedMethodsBoundObject.cs you can dig through the example projects to see most of the features demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty old, but I figured I would add an answer in case anyone runs into it as well.

I have a similar setup to you that requires authentication prior to running each test, so prior to moving on with a test I will wait for elements to load (without checking the `DocumentCompleted()` method).

What I do is use a helper that takes in some condition, in my case it's `Func<bool>`, then checks for this condition every time period x, until a timeout of y. Both X and Y are configurable, but they have a default of say 1 second and 10 seconds. You can make the implementation decision on whether or not to suppress exceptions inside the method, but I would recommend doing it so that ElementNotFound exceptions do not stop the execution.

The timing helper function definition note: time in milli-seconds.

```
public static bool WaitFor(Func<bool> condition, int timeout = 10000, int waitTimePeriod = 1000)
```

Examples of use would be:

- Waiting for an element on the page to finish loading (if the component has a loading indicator)
- Waiting for an element to appear in the DOM
- Waiting for an element to be removed from the DOM