# How to trigger a javascript event when a button becomes visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using some third party js and html library(I don't want to update this library). There is an "apply all" button in HTML and what I want to do is "click this button when it becomes visible."

```
<div class="confirm" ng-show="newFilters.length">
    ....
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Apply All</button>
</div>
```

EDIT: When the button becomes visible click function should trigger.

Comment: What do you mean by "click this button when it becomes visible." ? Do you mean when the button becomes visible, click function should trigger?

Comment: @Thinker yes of course.

Comment: See [jQuery event to trigger action when a div is made visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible) and [jQuery when element becomes visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487472/jquery-when-element-becomes-visible).

Comment: What event makes the button visible?

Comment: Well you can write code that runs in a timer and checks if it is visible. Horrible idea, but only option if you do not want to look at the code and see if there is something that triggers it to show up and piggy back off that.

Comment: check if(attr('display','block')){//Do whatever You Wish}

Comment: What means 'visible'? If scrolled to screen, or added to the DOM or changing any css property to make it visible???

Comment: @DavidThomas There is a div as parent element <div class="confirm" ng-show="newFilters.length">

Comment: So at least add relevant tag in question (angularjs?!)

Comment: @A.Wolff Do we need angularjs to trigger button click event?

Comment: @hellzone No but the way you are thinking about your workaround seems wrong. This is something you should handle the angular's way, not the jQuery's one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#observe()) that will listen for changes in css of element and then you can run click event when change happens.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('button').css('display', 'block');
}, 2000);

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if ($('button').css('display') !== 'none') {
      $('button').click();
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document.querySelector('button'), {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['style']
});

$('button').click(function() {
  alert('clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="display: none;">Apply All</button>
```

Comment: Your code display `clicked` alert if you change another style of button. See https://jsfiddle.net/zw3nzehk/

Comment: @Mohammad Yes you are right, i updated my answer now it will run click event only when `display` property is changed.

Comment: See interessting approach "ClassWatcher" from TecWisdom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612024/event-trigger-on-a-class-change). It wraps MutationObserver.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this....

```
if($('#Element_name').is(':visible'))
{
    // you code goes here
}
```

Comment: Problem is I dont know when it will become visible and I need to check periodically which is bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

As epascarello, we can use a timer to check whether the button is visible or not. So, you can use `setInterval` in your code.

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($("#show").is(':visible')){
    console.log("run the code");
  }
},2000);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/qtgj07jf/1/) link

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
<div class="confirm" ng-show="newFilters.length">
    ....
    <button ng-click="newFilters.length && myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">Apply All</button>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.myFunction(){
    console.log("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($("button.btn").is(':visible')){
    $(this).trigger('click');
    alert('button click');
  }
},1000);
```

it check every 1 second that button is visible or not and if visible trigger button click

Comment: your timeout is set to 1 second, meaning it can become visible and wait one full second until anything executes. What the OP wants to know is more closely related to an event that fires when an element becomes visible, or changes its `display` property. Think of events, "when X happens, Y executes"